# Drop down slide menu for iPhone web app

Tags: jquery, iphone, web-applications, drop-down-menu

I'm creating a iPhone web app and want to add a drop down menu in the top menu bar to preserve page space. How would I get the menu to slide? I currently have all my list items in a unordered list in a div. I have jQuery installed so can use that.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with the jQuery .slideDown() property. See this [link](http://api.jquery.com/slideDown/) for more